# Auto update of MySql row numbering

Tags: mysql

I have made a table in MySql with a column "id" as auto_increment and Primary_key. I initially made 3 rows, namely 1,2,3. I deleted no. 2 row but the numbering remains 1, 3. How do I change it to 1,2.
[MySql Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUvVS.png)

Comment: Is it absolutely important that it is sequential? The `1` and `3` are just making it unique.

Comment: Yeah! I need it to be serially listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **you don't**. Changing this is a multi step problem that can be very error prone if you don't do it right. Frankly, it rarely (if ever) makes sense to do so.

Things involved in such a task:

1. Delete a row you don't want (you've done that)
2. Subtract 1 from the `id` of every `id` that's `>=` to the row you just deleted.
3. Update the auto increment counter to be at 1 less than the current.
4. Do the same thing for all tables in which this is a foreign key.

If you want to delete multiple rows, the logic gets much more complicated very quickly. Either way, it will take considerable resources and will wreak havoc with your foreign keys.

Such an action really goes against the principles of how one would normally use a database. An RDMS is not a flat file like an excel spreadsheet. Just delete the rows and let there be a gap in the auto incremented ID, it really doesn't make any difference whatsoever to your application.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Actually I do really need the ID column. You see, it is an online examination portal. The admin needs to know the serial number of the question he's about to delete.

Comment: I found out a way. It's crude but it works. I delete the entire column and create it once again before the user/admin enters the deleting option.

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OnlineExamination","root","root");
 PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("alter table qna_c drop id");
 int r=ps.executeUpdate();
 ps=conn.prepareStatement("alter table qna_c add column id int not null auto_increment primary key first");
 r=ps.executeUpdate();
 ps=conn.prepareStatement("delete from qna_c where id=?");
 ps.setInt(1, id);
 r=ps.executeUpdate();